# How often does the GPS check for location changes

Tags: android, gps, location, proximity

How often does the GPS check for location changes **without being specifically asked with requestLocationUpdates**? Does that change when the screen is off?

My app just sets up a proximity alert, without any background service running, and it plays a sound when entering the proximity. I'm trying to find out the limitations to this approach, if there are any.

Answer (score 0):

As long as  the GPS chip is enabled it sends 1 location per second to the API.